# Reading file into table using PHP

Tags: php, html, html-table

I will start by saying I am fairly new to all HTML/CSS/PHP, but particularly PHP. I have a page, index.php that is just some basic HTML for the page, but I need the PHP for a script to read data from a couple files into a HTML table.

```
<table id="table">
            <?php
            $names = fopen("names.txt", "r") or die("Error, unable to open name file!");
            $costs = fopen("cost.txt", "r") or die("Error, unable to open cost file!");
            $name = file("names.txt");
            echo $name[0];
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?phpecho ($name[0]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?phpecho ($name[1]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?phpecho ($name[2]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?phpecho ($name[3]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?phpecho ($name[4]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?phpecho ($name[5]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?phpecho ($name[6]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?phpecho ($name[7]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?phpecho ($name[8]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?phpecho ($name[9]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?phpecho ($name[10]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?phpecho ($name[11]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                </tr>
```

In this excerpt of my code, the `echo $name[0];` is just to test if that works, and that part does, it prints out the first line of the file. However the rest of the calls in the `<td></td>` do absolutely nothing. Neither of the versions of code prints anything, just a blank table. The first method is to use an array with every line in it and call the lines, and the second method is to use the `fgets()` function to read 1 line into the `<td></td>` and the pointer automatically moves to the next line. Either way should get the job done for reading the file out line by line, but I don't understand what is tripping me up here. Again, I am very new to PHP, so this could be a very newbie error, if so, I apologize in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's becuase there is no space between opening php tag and echo. try this:

```
<tr>
                    <td><?php echo ($name[0]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($name[1]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($name[2]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($name[3]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($name[4]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($name[5]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($name[6]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($name[7]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($name[8]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($name[9]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($name[10]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($name[11]); echo fgets($costs);?></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Ha! That was it, wow, thanks! I thought it was something far more complicated than just a simple stupid mistake, I may be new to PHP, but I'm not that new to coding, should have caught that error. Thanks! Would you suggest one method over the other? My preference is `fgets()` since I don't have to change anything for all the code.